# Not able to apply interval arithmetic using Saxon processor

Tags: java, xml, xquery, saxon, xbrl

I'm using **Saxon processor** to execute the validations.
 The file which contains all the function definition is as below:
**default-definition.txt**:

```
declare variable $a external; 
declare variable $b external; 
declare variable $c external; 

declare function iaf:sum(
$params as item()*
) as item()+ {

  let $facts := if (empty($params)) then (0) else one-or-more($params)
  let $values := for $i in $facts return (iaf:splitValueThreshold($i)[1])
  let $thresholds := for $i in $facts return (iaf:splitValueThreshold($i)[2])
  let $sumValues := sum($values)
  let $sumThresholds := sum($thresholds)
  let $output := iaf:joinValueThreshold($sumValues, $sumThresholds) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-equal(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as xs:boolean {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := abs($itemA[1] - $itemB[1]) le ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2]) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-less-than(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as xs:boolean {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := ($itemA[1] - $itemB[1]) lt ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2]) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-less-equal-than(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as xs:boolean {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := ($itemA[1] - $itemB[1]) le ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2]) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-greater-than(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as xs:boolean {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := $itemA[1] gt ($itemB[1] - ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2])) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-greater-equal-than(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as xs:boolean {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := $itemA[1] ge ($itemB[1] - ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2])) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-add(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $value := $itemA[1]+$itemB[1]
  let $threshold := $itemA[2]+$itemB[2]
  let $output := iaf:joinValueThreshold($value,$threshold) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-subtract(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $value := $itemA[1]-$itemB[1]
  let $threshold := $itemA[2]+$itemB[2]
  let $output := iaf:joinValueThreshold($value,$threshold) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-divide(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $A := $itemA[1]
  let $B := $itemB[1]
  let $deltaA := $itemA[2]
  let $deltaB := $itemB[2]
  let $AdivB := $A div $B
  let $J0 := ($A + $deltaA) div ($B + $deltaB)
  let $J1 := ($A + $deltaA) div ($B - $deltaB)
  let $J2 := ($A - $deltaA) div ($B + $deltaB)
  let $J3 := ($A - $deltaA) div ($B - $deltaB)
  let $threshold := max((abs($AdivB - $J0), abs($AdivB - $J1), abs($AdivB - $J2), abs($AdivB - $J3)))
  let $output := iaf:joinValueThreshold($AdivB, $threshold) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-multiply(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {
  iaf:multiply-two-elements($paramA, $paramB)
};

declare function iaf:numeric-multiply(
$params as item()+
) as item() {

  let $output := iaf:multiply-recursive($params, 1, 0) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:abs(
$input as item()
) as item() {

  let $item := if (empty($input)) then 0 else $input
  let $output := if ($item instance of element() and empty($item[2])) then
    iaf:joinValueThreshold(abs($item), iaf-int:fact-threshold($item)) else (if (not($item instance of
    element()) and empty($item[2]) and not(contains(string($item), ";"))) then
    iaf:joinValueThreshold(abs($item), 0) else
    iaf:joinValueThreshold(abs(xs:decimal(substring-before($item, ";"))),
    xs:decimal(substring-after($item, ";"))))  
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-unary-minus(
$item as item()
) as item() {

  let $output := if ($item instance of element() and empty($item[2])) then
    iaf:joinValueThreshold(-($item), iaf-int:fact-threshold($item)) else (if (not($item instance of
    element()) and empty($item[2]) and not(contains(string($item), ";"))) then
    iaf:joinValueThreshold(-($item), 0) else
    iaf:joinValueThreshold(-(xs:decimal(substring-before($item, ";"))),
    xs:decimal(substring-after($item, ";"))))  
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:min(
$params as item()*
) as item() {

  let $facts := if (empty($params)) then (0) else one-or-more($params)
  let $values := for $i in $facts return (iaf:splitValueThreshold($i)[1])
  let $thresholds := for $i in $facts return (iaf:splitValueThreshold($i)[2])
  let $minValue := min($values)
  let $indexMin := index-of($values, $minValue)[1]
  let $minThreshold := $thresholds[$indexMin]
  let $output := iaf:joinValueThreshold($minValue,$minThreshold) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:max(
$params as item()*
) as item() {

  let $facts := if (empty($params)) then (0) else one-or-more($params)
  let $values := for $i in $facts return (iaf:splitValueThreshold($i)[1])
  let $thresholds := for $i in $facts return (iaf:splitValueThreshold($i)[2])
  let $maxValue := max($values)
  let $indexMax := index-of($values, $maxValue)[1]
  let $maxThreshold := $thresholds[$indexMax]
  let $output := iaf:joinValueThreshold($maxValue,$maxThreshold) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:splitValueThreshold(
$item as item()
) as item()+ {

  let $valorUmbral := if ($item instance of element() and empty($item[2])) then ($item,
    iaf-int:fact-threshold($item)) else (if (not($item instance of element()) and empty($item[2])
    and not(contains(string($item), ";"))) then ($item, 0) else
    (xs:decimal(substring-before($item, ";")), xs:decimal(substring-after($item, ";"))))  
       return ($valorUmbral)

};

declare function iaf:joinValueThreshold(
$value as item(), $threshold as item()
) as xs:string {

  let $output := concat(string($value),";",string($threshold)) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:precision(
$item as item()+
) as xs:decimal {

  let $ouput := xfi:decimals($item) 
       return ($ouput)

};

declare function iaf:multiply-recursive(
$sequence as item()+, $count as item(), $subtotalParam as item()
) as item() {

  let $facts := if (empty($sequence)) then (0) else
    one-or-more($sequence)
  let $numberOfParams := count($facts)
  let $subtotal := if ($count eq 1) then $facts[1] else $subtotalParam
  let $multiply := if($count lt $numberOfParams) then iaf:multiply-two-elements($subtotal,
    $facts[$count + 1]) else $subtotal
  let $output := if($count lt $numberOfParams) then iaf:multiply-recursive($sequence,
    ($count +1), $multiply) else $multiply 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:multiply-two-elements(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $A := $itemA[1]
  let $B := $itemB[1]
  let $deltaA := $itemA[2]
  let $deltaB := $itemB[2]
  let $AxB := $A * $B
  let $threshold := sum((abs($A * $deltaB), abs($B * $deltaA), $deltaA * $deltaB)) 
       return (iaf:joinValueThreshold($AxB, $threshold))

};

declare function iaf:numeric-equal-threshold(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2]) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-less-than-threshold(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2]) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-less-equal-than-threshold(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2]) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-greater-than-threshold(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2]) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:numeric-greater-equal-than-threshold(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item() {

  let $itemA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)
  let $itemB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)
  let $output := ($itemA[2] + $itemB[2]) 
       return ($output)

};

declare function iaf:abs-sequence(
$params as item()*
) as item()+ {

  let $facts := if (empty($params)) then (0) else one-or-more($params)
  let $values := for $i in $facts return (iaf:abs($i)) 
       return (($values))

};

declare function iaf:numeric-equal-test(
$paramA as item(), $paramB as item()
) as item()+ {

  let $valueA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)[1]
  let $valueB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)[1]
  let $thA := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramA)[2]
  let $thB := iaf:splitValueThreshold($paramB)[2]
  let $absol := abs($valueA - $valueB)
  let $sumTh := $thA + $thB 
       return (($valueA, $valueB, $thA, $thB, $absol, $sumTh))

};

declare function iaf-int:exp10(
$power as xs:integer
) as xs:decimal {
  if ($power eq 0) then 1 else if ($power gt 0) then 10 * iaf-int:exp10($power - 1) else 1 div iaf-int:exp10(-$power)
};

declare function iaf-int:fact-threshold(
$fact as item()
) as xs:decimal {

  let $decimals := xfi:decimals($fact) 
       return (if (string($decimals) = 'INF') then 0 else iaf-int:exp10(-xs:integer($decimals)) div 2)

};
declare function xff:has-fallback-value(
$fact as xs:QName
) as xs:boolean{
            let $result := if (string($a) = '') then fn:true() else fn:false()
            return ($result)
};
declare function xfi:decimals($fact as item() ) as item()+ { let $deci := $fact/@decimals  return ($deci)};
declare function xfi:fact-typed-dimension-value($fact as item() , $typedDim as xs:QName?) as xs:string {let $dimName := substring-before(substring-after($fact,concat("s2c_dim:",$typedDim,"__TDVALUE__")),";") return ($dimName)};
$a = +$b + $c
```

**Junit TestCase**:

```
XdmValue xqueryResult = null;
XQueryCompiler xqueryCompiler = new Processor(false).newXQueryCompiler();
declareNamespace(xqueryCompiler);
XQueryExecutable queryExecutable = xqueryCompiler.compile(new File("default-definition.txt")); //I18NOK:LSM
XQueryEvaluator xqueryEvaluator = queryExecutable.load();
double aa=331640738.91;
double bb=393432239.2;
double cc=-61791500.29;

//previous strategy, which is now throwing an exception
//  XPTY0004: Cannot compare xs:string to xs:double
xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("a"), new XdmAtomicValue(String.format("%s;%s", aa,FactValue.getPrecision("-3"))));
xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("b"), new XdmAtomicValue(bb));
xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("c"), new XdmAtomicValue(cc));
xqueryEvaluator.toString();
xqueryResult = xqueryEvaluator.evaluate();
System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(xqueryResult.itemAt(0).getStringValue()));

//exact match --Result: FAIL
xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("a"), new XdmAtomicValue(aa));
xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("b"), new XdmAtomicValue(bb));
xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("c"), new XdmAtomicValue(cc));
xqueryEvaluator.toString();
xqueryResult = xqueryEvaluator.evaluate();
System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(xqueryResult.itemAt(0).getStringValue()));

//matching after rounding off till the range of 1000 --Result: FAIL
double a = Math.round(Double.parseDouble("331640738.91") * Math.pow(10,-3)) / Math.pow(10,-3);
double b = Math.round(Double.parseDouble("393432239.2") * Math.pow(10,-3)) / Math.pow(10,-3);
double c = Math.round(Double.parseDouble("-61791500.29") * Math.pow(10,-3)) / Math.pow(10,-3);

xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("a"), new XdmAtomicValue(a));
xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("b"), new XdmAtomicValue(b));
xqueryEvaluator.setExternalVariable(new QName("c"), new XdmAtomicValue(c));
xqueryEvaluator.toString();
xqueryResult = xqueryEvaluator.evaluate();
System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(xqueryResult.itemAt(0).getStringValue()));
```

Ideally, the difference between the value of "a" and "b+c" is in decimals and it should pass. Please let me know if there is another way to execute interval arithmetic using Saxon.
Please let me know if anymore inputs are needed.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the assertion

```
assertEquals(aa, bb+cc);
```

to your Java code immediately after declaring these variables, you will see that it fails:

```
Expected (aa) :3.3164073891E8
Actual(bb+cc) :3.3164073890999997E8
```

The failure is because of rounding errors converting the values you have written (such as 331640738.91) to the nearest value that is expressible within the double-precision value space.

Java is using exactly the same rules for double-precision floating point arithmetic that XQuery is using, so I can't see why you would expect it to succeed in XQuery when it fails in Java.

If you want to use exact decimal arithmetic then you need to use the `xs:decimal` data type rather than `xs:double`.

Comment: Thank you for answering again! It worked after changing the data type to BigDecimal.

Comment: One more question, the error is thrown by the Saxon processor while executing the validation, then how can I set the data type to `xs:decimal`? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You've given us 450 lines of XQuery code to work with, I'm not going to work through all the places that need to change if the data type is xs:decimal rather than xs:double. It's quite a bit of work because you haven't declared any data types for your variables or params, which makes the query much harder to understand. Also, you know what the error message is, I don't.